# count query with joins in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I try to create a count query in SQL, and I try to show notifications to supervisor, manager and director when any users uploaded new documents in asp.net

Query

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[countdocuments]
   @DepID int
as
    SELECT 
       COUNT(*),
       Designation.DesigID
    FROM DocumentInfo
    INNER JOIN dbo.Userss ON dbo.Userss.DesigID = dbo.Designation.DesigID
    WHERE 
       Userss.DesigID = 'Finance'
```

but when I execute it, the following error occurs

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure countdocuments, Line 7
>   The multi-part identifier "dbo.Designation.DesigID" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure countdocuments, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "Designation.DesigID" could not be bound.

OK this is my `designation` table

```
DesigID   DesigType
  1       SuperVisor
  2       Manager
  3       Director
  4       BasicUsers
```

and this is `documentinfo` table

```
DocID  DocDescrit  DocName UploadedDate Uploadfile DocTypeID DepID ApproveID UploadedBy UserID
32  asp.net codescomputer 2013-12-30 22:30:00.623    details.docx   1   2   1amna   24
```

and this is `userss` table

```
UserID UserName Password UserTypeID DepID CreateDate Email PhoeNumber DesigID
21  john    abc 2   NULL    NULL    2013-12-02 22:01:03.903 NULL    abc@hotmail.com 12313   4
```

and when I try this query

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[countdocuments]
    @DepID int
as
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS Cnt, Designation.DesigID
    FROM 
        Designation 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Userss ON dbo.Userss.DesigID = dbo.Designation.DesigID
    WHERE 
        Userss.DesigID = @DepID
    GROUP BY 
        Designation.DesigID
END
```

when I try to execute like with `@depid = 4` this show me like this and I don't understand where is 4 coming from..

```
Cnt  DesigID
 4     4
```

Comment: +5 :O and no one answer  me ... :/

Comment: This is because it is not able to find column name DesigId in table Designation. Where is Designation table? Or do you meant to put alias to DocumentInfo as Designation table

Comment: Can you provide the Schema?

Comment: in documnet info table there is no coulmn named desigid ..desigid is only in userss table and in desig table there are two columns one is desigid and other is desigtype

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[countdocuments]
@DepID int
as
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt,Designation.DesigID
    FROM DocumentInfo inner join dbo.Userss 
    on dbo.Userss.DesigID = dbo.DocumentInfo.DesigID
    WHERE Userss.DesigID = @DepID
    GROUP BY DocumentInfo.DesigID

END
```

You have different Table Names in you `JOIN` clause and `ON` clause. I have tried to fix it assuming you have `DesigID` column in your `DocumentInfo` table.

Comment: i have desigid coulmn only in userss and in designation table

Comment: yours and my answer will not work as he has already said that he doesnt have DesigId in documentInfo table

Comment: @user3134694 Do you have any column in `DocumentInfo` that refers to any column in `Designation` ???

Comment: @user3134694 can you update you question and provide information about all three Tables and Columns in them tables, and any Foreign Keys in them tables.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment try following

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[countdocuments]
@DepID int
as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt,Designation.DesigID
FROM Designation left join dbo.Userss 
on dbo.Userss.DesigID = dbo.Designation.DesigID
left Join DocumentInfo on Userss.UserId= DocumentInfo.UserId and Designation.DepId = DocumentInfo.DepId
WHERE Userss.DesigID = @DepID
GROUP BY Designation.DesigID

END
```

Or try below

```
Looking at your comment try following

ALTER procedure [dbo].[countdocuments]
@DepID int
as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt,Designation.DesigID
FROM DocumentInfo  left Join Userss on DocumentInfo.UserId = Userss.UserId
left Join Designation on DocumentInfo.DepId = Designation.DeptId
and Designation.DesigID = Userss.DesigId
WHERE Userss.DesigID = @DepID
GROUP BY Designation.DesigID

END
```

Comment: in documentinfo table there is not a column DesigID

Comment: Then why you have added DocumentInfo table. Where is join to Desig table?

Comment: @user3134694 What is relation between users and Desig table?

Comment: when nay users signup then his/her desig is save in table ..and identify which user belong to which which designations

Comment: @user3134694 I am asking which column you can link between users and Designation table?

Comment: the coulmn link desigid

Comment: @user3134694 which column is common between documentinfo and users table?

Comment: this  return me like this Cnt DesigID  4 4  when i write 4 ...,,i dnt understand i want for e.g when user upload fianance document then when finance admin loign then he able to see notifications that 1 new document uploaded...

Comment: @user3134694 i asked which column is common between documentinfo and users table?

Comment: @user3134694 you never mentioned which column are related to each other. Try my updated answer and let me know immediately

Comment: i tell u that only depid and userid are in documentinfo and userss table

Comment: @user3134694 so what is link between documentinfo and userss table and Designation table?

Comment: @user3134694 please try updated answer again. Your question is very difficult to understand and thats the reason no one is able to answer you. You have just mentioned table names and column and not given information about how they are linked to each other. Are we god to understand relation between those tables?

Comment: @user3134694 did you tried my updated answer? Did you got correct output. In simple words just give me relation between table. When i say relation then give me which column are linked to each table.

Comment: yes when i excute ur query like this countdocuments 3 this will reurturn me "(Coulmns Name)Cnt DeisgID  1 3" and when i write 2 instead of 3 then can not return me anything

Comment: @user3134694 what output are you expecting then? I have added left join instead of inner join. Can you try my updated answer and let me know. I am really tired now. Your question is not clear and nor your table structure

Comment: @user3134694 i have added another query. Do let me know if it works

Comment: i just want to show notifications to manager  ,supervisor to sql query that new document is uploaded like this suppose this is tab approvedocuments (1) here (1) means new documents is uploaded

Comment: @user3134694 i am really sorry i cannot help you further. Your question is not clear and nor is your table structure

Comment: its ok and thanks u so much for cooperating and suggesting me